# select distinct row using single column value in Athena

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-athena, presto

I am a newbie to database, so thanks for helping out.

Given a table with 10 columns A, B, C, D, ..... having lots of non unique value in all columns, how to get rows with distinct value in column A. So if there are 5 rows with value 'eureka' and 'hippie' each in column A, I need single row for each.

And it will be great if you can tell me multiple solutions and compare them with SQL counterpart. I searched it can be done with GROUP BY and PARTITION BY but somehow I am not able to get query work in Athena. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by a) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even I was able to figure out solution later, initially I was using Distinct(header1), rest_headers... but later realise it will not work and got confused. Yups Row_Number() was to be used.